# Loading Json Data into TableView

Tags: ios, json

I have downloaded from PocketApp (Loading Json Data) from Github as per link: https://github.com/vaibhavgupta06/PocketApp-Test.

But the link to retrieve JSON database was gone already.
http://dev.pocketapp.co.uk:8080/PocketAppTestData-0.1/book/listAsJson

Could anyone help me find the JSON file for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your code done so far

Comment: I just need a JSON file only. I want to test it with this app. and want to create a JSON file like that.

Comment: ask to author of  library .

Comment: Why do you use a 4-year old library without any documentation and with a rating of zero?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to infer the schema based on the code.  It is an array of books with an author property.  I wrote the schema here: https://gist.github.com/jonathanRose/87d70449a3a1df3f1bae1f6d6d4a7971
and an exampled based on it here:
https://gist.github.com/jonathanRose/835f80844783170285d94615a1a07069

good luck.

Comment: Hi Jon Rose, Thank you very much.. But, moreover, I want to store the database to the PHPMyAdmin and the URL that I want to retrieve data is http://localhost/book.php 
Could you help me create the "book.php" file and the "book.sql" file?

Comment: The library you linked to was a demo project that someone wrote 4 years ago.  I uses JSON and core-data and is pretty simple.  If you want to learn from it then it is OK, but not great.  Making it the backbone of your project is silly.

Comment: Hi Jon Rose, I do not know how to make use of JSON file that you created.. Could you teach me how to use that.. Thank you so much..